# How do I use old membership system of ASP.NET 2 instead of ASP.NET Identity in ASP.NET 4.5?

Tags: asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity

I am working on a web application and I need to use a legacy membership system. Can you help me to know how should I have that database and how to implement that membership system in my web application that uses .Net 4.5?
let me explain it, you know nowadays we are using ASP.NET Identity but if you remember in past we were using ASP.NET Membership in .Net 2, can you remember old membership and authentication system? now i want to use that system instead of ASP.NET Identity. with old tables and structure.

Comment: This question would be better if you gave more details and explained what you've already tried so far.

Comment: For starters, which legacy sysem?

Comment: i explained it, i want to use membership system of .Net 2 in new .Net, i don't want to use ASP.NET Identity

Comment: Start by creating a .NET 3.5 Web app, that is still possible in VS2015 but maybe the templates in an older VS are better for this. Use it for a starting point or as a reference.

Comment: When you can figure out the Hashing scheme in Membership then you can easily use an old Db in a new MVC app. Otherwise, try referencing the old Membership DLLs and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the history -

1. Membership Provider
2. Universal Providers
3. Simple Membership
4. ASP.NET Identity (Current version is 2)

**[ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx)** is the last version of old ASP.Net Membership Provider. It uses **Entity Framework Code First** under the hood.

If you really have to use **ASP.Net 2.0 Membership Provider**, you need to use **aspnet_regsql.exe** to generate schema and store procedures. It is pain in the neck.

Here is the step-by-step instruction at 4guysfromrolla - [Examining ASP.NET's Membership, Roles, and Profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx)